# Python .get from a Nested Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

There are a number of none try/except ways to obtain a key or `None` from a Python dictionary, the problem is I can't seem to find an effective way of doing it for a Nested dictionary, i.e. where I need `my_dict['author']['email']` since chaining `.get()` twice will hit a Nonetype. 
I thought of extending the dictionary `.get()` to be able to chain nested dicts i.e `.get(['author']['email'])` - but that would mean I'd have to re-initiate everything into the custom dictionary type (I think)?

The specific situation is I have two-schema's by which data is stored in Mongodb for a small transition, and I'm trying to find the optimal way to fetch the right information. (All the data before storage is verified to be one of two schemas).

So for example on a non-nested item, stored differently in the schemas one might do:

```
#get database_info
author_name = database_info['author'] if database_info.get('author') else database_info['author_name']
```

or

```
author_name = database_info['author'] if 'author' in database_info else database_info['author_name']
```

But for `database_info['author']['email']` (Where Author is a dictionary object containing other keys,values), one must do:

```
try: author_email = database_info['author']['email']
except: database_info['contributor']['email_address']
```

Is there an optimal way to one line this? One way I've thought about attacking it is like this (for an arbitrary path of nested dictionaries):

```
author_email = database_info['author']['email'] if database_info.get('author', {}).get('email') else database_info['contributor']['email_address']
```

Comment: might help if you posted an example of your dict structure

Comment: Can you determine the schema before performing the accesses?  If so, then you can just select between two functions which perform the access directly.

Comment: I can but I actually think the code will be more concise than having two separate functions for two different schema's, because a good deal of the schema's are the same. Of course I could literally do if valite(item_data, schema1): elif validate(item_data, schema2)

Comment: [funcy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/funcy) has a few mapping/collection functions just for this purpose.

Comment: Why are people down voting this, it seems what the best way to get a a nested dict value or None in an efficient way is a very legitimate question?

Comment: If the only differences in the schemas are the names of the fields, then you should extract the names into a data structure and pass that into the `validate()` function (as you said), otherwise it might just be a case of writing two classes related by inheritance where you are programming by difference.

Comment: write a function `nested_get(root_dict, *vargs, default=None)` which contains the functionality you need for as many levels deep a dict as you want.  That'll keep it clean and not make a mess of your overall functions.

Comment: Don't be afraid to try-except. Python programming culture takes a very different approach to exceptions than you might find in other languages; it's frequently actually preferred to see whether you can do something by trying to do it and catching the exception if you can't.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a general solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


from __future__ import print_function


def select(d, *keys, **options):
    try:
        for key in keys:
            d = d[key]
        return d
    except:
        if "default" in options:
            return options["default"]
        raise


d = {
    "foo": {
        "bar": {
            "baz": 1
        }
    }
}


print(select(d, "foo", "bar", "baz"))
```

**Output:**

```
$ python foo.py 
1
```

Some other usage(s):

```
$ python -i foo.py 
1
>>> select(d, "foobar")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "foo.py", line 10, in select
    d = d[key]
KeyError: 'foobar'
>>> select(d, "foobar", default="Not Found")
'Not Found'
>>>
```

*Inspired by [funcy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/funcy) but my own spin on the equivalent function*.

Answer (score 1):

The simple case is

```
author_name = database_info.get('author') or database_info['author_name']
```

the two-folded case

```
author_email = database_info.get('author', {}).get('email') or database_info['contributor']['email_address']
```